# Typical Farming Economics Resource

Tags: data-request, research

Are there any resources available that provide typical books or accounts for the farming or indeed other industries?

Something that would list, employee numbers, wage bills, expenditure income (sales vs subsidies) and so on in terms understandable to a layman?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have many books to share but there is the website on Farm economy data from the USDA.

Farm Labor
USDA Economic Research Service (ERS)

https://www.ers.usda.gov/topics/farm-economy/farm-labor/

There is also the USDA National Agricultural Statistics Service (feel free to explore their site)

https://www.nass.usda.gov/Data_and_Statistics/index.php

here are some articles

https://arefiles.ucdavis.edu/uploads/filer_public/ad/74/ad7450e7-80ab-4cf7-a147-6b80c2e614a7/chapter_1_the_farm_labor_problem_4-4-17.pdf
The Farm Labor Problem
J. Edward Taylor & Diane Charlton
Agricultural & Resource Economics
University of California, Davis

https://www.bls.gov/opub/mlr/2014/article/agriculture-occupational-employment-and-wages.htm
Agriculture: occupational employment and wages

Labour Market Effects of Large-Scale Agricultural Investment: Conceptual Considerations and Estimated Employment Effects
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0305750X17301754

Few books on the subject:

freebook-
The Economics of Food and Agricultural Markets - 2nd Edition
https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/textbooks/the-economics-of-food-and-agricultural-markets

Agricultural Economics (3rd Edition) 3rd Edition
by H. Evan Drummond Ph.D. (Author), John W. Goodwin (Author)